# Failed to load .NET framework 4.0 dll from .NET 6 project

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, .net-6.0

I have a .NET 6 project and try to load a third-party dll, which build with .NET framework 4.0, dependencies are `mscorelib`, `System.Configuration`, `System.Data`, `System.Drawing` and `System.Core`, all are version 4.0.

When I run into the method, the application crashes with exception:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly '**dll, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.

Seems there are some version conflict between dependent assemblies, but some .NET framework 2.0 dlls works fine. How to resolve this problem if I cannot ask the dll verdor to build a new one?

Comment: you can't blindly reference .net framework assemblies from .net (core) ones. you should attempt to find updated versions for the third party library

Comment: @DanielA.White but some .net framework 2.0 dlls can work, what's the difference between 2.0 and 4.0?

Comment: @Lamp: It has nothing to do with 2.0 vs 4.0: .NET 6 contains *some* of the classes/methods from .NET Framework 2.0 and *some* of the classes/methods from .NET Framework 4.0 (and a lot of new classes/methods). If the one your library needs is there, good, otherwise, bad luck. Only the creator of the third-party DLL can change which classes/methods it uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a library uses functions for the .NET Framework, it cannot run on the .NET Core. If it doesn’t, building to the .NET Standard allows it to run on both. Either:

The library is not usable on the .NET Core, in which case your out of luck,

it has separate builds for .NET Framework and .NET Core, in which case you would need to choose the right one,

or the library developer only compiled it for the .NET Framework when it could be compiled otherwise, in which case you could try to compile it yourself.